# Store password for passing to another service

Tags: java, security, passwords, jira, password-storage

I wrote an app that queries a Jira API which requires authentication that I provide through Basic Authentication (base64 in the header). The password was stored in the code which has to stop now because I want to hand over the code.

When the users changes their passwords due to the password schedule, the app should prompt the user for the new Jira password, save it securely, and pass it to the Jira API via Basic Authentication.

What's the best way to do this?

Normally, we would hash it but that's not possible because hashing is one-way direction and we need to pass in the real password to Jira instead of a hash.

Comment: You're going to store the password in a database right? If so, there is a possibility to use hashing with salt on your code to hash and convert back to a normal string the passwords.

Comment: Hashing is a one way "encryption" so It's not possible to convert a hash back to a string. Using symmetric encryption like AES, what you say is possible but anyone with access to the code could decypher all the passwords because the program would have to have access to the encryption key.

Comment: I think most of the common applications have the encryption key stored in the code. What you can do is store the encryption key in the database and configure the table security so only the application has the access to read it. You can do this with Row Level Security (e.g https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-data-security-feature-rls-row-level-security-and-gdpr/)

Answer (score 1):

In case of storing a string which needs to be protected in case of breaches or as a general software data security concern, encryptions should be done. For example, in your case, when the password is taken by the user then it shall be encrypted by the software before storing. While retrieving, the password is decrypted and converted to the hash(or base64) which Jira accepts for the login handshake.

Apart from the simply encrypting and decrypting, a better approach will be to use salts while encrypting and using multiple encryptions in the loop to avoid brute force attempts.

Pseudocode:

```
unsafe_password = getPasswordFromUser()
salt = getRandomString();
safePassword = encrypt(unsafe_password, salt, key)

// Store the password
putEntryInDB(user, safePassword, salt)

// Retrieve password
[passwordSalt, encryptedPassword] = getSaltAndEncryptedPasswordFromDB()

unsafePassword = decrypt(encryptedPassword, passwordSalt, key)

// Now login into Jira with the actual user's password (unsafePassword)

P.S. You'll be needing to store a key in the code or in some software's configuration.
```

Source: Attempt 4&5 https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/

Comment: Adding a salt to the symmetric encryption seems like a useful practice.

Comment: Definitely, I agree. Also, I feel now that we do need newer approaches as quantum computing is about fly high!